# How do I add and subtract a number in a jQuery .click function?

Tags: jquery

I will use jQuery to perform the following:

Upon click of elements with the class "checkbox":

- add class "checkmark"
- remove class "checkbox"
- update a div with "You have x apps in your request list" where x is the number that have been clicked
- When a class with "checkmark" has been clicked, it will subtract from the number that is displayed

My example code does not show all of this function, but I am able to accomplish this except for updating the number that have been clicked / "unclicked".

`

```
$("span.checkbox").click(function() {

    if(!oldVal) {
        var oldVal = "0";
    }

    var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) + 1;

    var oldVal = newVal;

    $("#wishlistapps").html('<li>You have ' + newVal + ' apps in your request list</li>');


});
```

`

Comment: Do you have many checkboxes (like hundreds), or just a few? Because if it's just a few, there's a simpler way: `$('.checkmark').length` will give you the number of items with class "checkmark".

Comment: Not hundreds, but more than 50, and growing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to declare your counter variable outside the click handler. The way you are currently doing, `oldVal` will *always* be zero when the handler is invoked.

```
var totalChecked = 0;
$("span.checkbox, span.checkmark").click(function() {
     var el = $(this);
     if(el.hasClass('checkbox')) {
         el.removeClass('checkbox');
         el.addClass('checkmark');
         totalChecked++;
     } else {
         el.removeClass('checkmark');
         el.addClass('checkbox');
         totalChecked--;
     }
     $("#wishlistapps").html('<li>You have ' + totalChecked + ' apps in your request list</li>');
});
```

Demo: http://jsbin.com/ufopok/2.

You can also use `$('.checkmark').length` as I said in the comment above, but it can get slow with many checkboxes.

Comment: the length thing worked, but I would rather use this if it's faster. Where did you get "checked"?

Comment: `checked` is a standard DOM property on checkboxes. But now I notice you're not using actual checkboxes... You can use `$(this).hasClass('checkmark')` instead if that's the case (please confirm, and I'll update my answer accordingly).

Comment: Correct. I'm not using actual checkboxes. It's simply a span with a background assigned to the class via css. jQuery is handling everything as it is clicked.

Comment: this worked on the test page, but for the actual page, it is not adding the class, so it goes into a negative count.

Comment: It works under the conditions you mentioned (see [demo](http://jsbin.com/ufopok/2)). There must be something different on your actual page.

Comment: It dawned on me! I was already adding and removing classes on the page. However, your way (together in one function) is better! Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10822/discussion-between-nitsuj-and-bfavaretto)